# How the javascript getElementById in another php?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to apply facebook login to my web application.

In order to split different parts, navigation bar, sidebar and content, into different php files, I need to use multiple

```
include('xxx.php');
```

in index.php

The script of facebook SDK is in index.php. When I use `getElementById()` in the script, it cannot find the element in `navigation.php`. The javascript can only find the element I needed when remove `include('xxx.php');` and move everything from  `xxx.php` to index.php at the line that I removed `include('xxx.php');`

If I want to keep using `include('xxx.php');`, how can I use `getElementById()` to find the elements in `xxx.php` when I call the function in `index.php`?

(I guess this kind of question has been asked before but I don't know how to call this kind of problem such that I don't know how to search for the solution)

Here are the codes in `index.php`:

```
<body>
<script>
...    
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // Logged into your app and Facebook.
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
            'into Facebook.';
    }
...
</script>
include('xxx.php');
```

The id `container` is in xxx.php.

Comment: *"When I use findElementById()"* . Please show the relevant code and html. None of this question makes much sense as it is

Comment: I have included some codes. I hope they are enough for you.

Comment: it should generally work, because its just a html thing for the browser even if you use `include`. give more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you calling `statusChangeCallback()` from? The inclusion of php files in your code takes place on the server side and is done before any output takes place. The javascript is executed in the user's browser once the completed page has been sent. So php include can not break this!

It is likely you are calling `statusChangeCallback()` in the wrong place so the function can not be found. You should either put the function after the call i.e. at the end of the included php content. Or you should wrap it in a `document.ready` function so that it is available only once the document has finished loading.

Comment: You are right. I should put the script at the end of the index.php. Thanks for saving my life.